# How do I use OR in laravel validate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

there is a form with a select field "state", the value of which must be "draft" or "published". how to do it? does not work now.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:article_categories' . $category->id,
    'description' => 'required|min:200',
    'state' => 'draft' || 'published'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **Rule::in([])**

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:article_categories' . $category->id,
    'description' => 'required|min:200',
    'state' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['draft', 'published']),
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `'state' => 'required|in:draft,published'`

Answer (score 0):

Is see you have answered your own question, but just to add to it: `'draft' || 'published'` evaluated in PHP as `true`.

Meaning you are actually doing this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    ....
    'state' => true
]);
```

which makes no sense in terms of what is expected in the validation rules.

The correct way to do this is as you said:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    ...
    'state' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['draft', 'published']),
    ]
]);
```